# Update % count with time diff

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this div where I want the output to update percentage count as the time progresses. For Example: I have startTime, NowTime and stopTime values. I have a div that displays the percentage(percentage that displays the difference b/w time). I want to update this percentage as the NowTime goes on and gets closer to stop time. I want it to start at 0% and finish at 100% when NowTime == StopTime.

Any Help is appreciated.

```
function cal(){
var NowTime = new Date(); //Time Now
var StartTime = new Date($('.StartTime').val());
var StopTime = new Date($('.StopTime').val());

var diffStpStr = Math.ceil(StopTime - StartTime); //diff b/w start and stop time    
var diffNwStr = Math.ceil(NowTime - StartTime); //StartTime in past
var Percent = (parseInt((diffNwStr/ ( diffStpStr/ 100)).toFixed(0)));
$('.CountPercentage').text(Percent + '%'); //% calculation  
}
setInterval = (cal,1000);
cal()
```

here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6LB76/91/
Problem: not being able to update. It shows and just stays but doesn't update. 
Thank You

Comment: What specific problem are you having?  You should include pertinent parts of your code in your question here as well.

Comment: Problem: not being able to update. It shows and just stays but doesn't update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setInterval = (cal,1000);` should be `setInterval(cal,1000);`

Update this and it works. This is because `setInterval` is a function (on the `window` object), so you need to call it, not assign it. JS doesn't throw an error for assignment, though, because you're just changing a property value (to `1000`, in this case).

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6LB76/92/)

Comment: Thanks You but I want to see it updating on the screen. I already have this working as in your working fiddle. sorry if there is any confusion in my question.

Comment: Did this answer your question, then? If so, you can check the little checkmark next to my answer to mark this as correct and the question as answered.